# Add a marker in openlayer map using the OpenLayers.Feature.Vector?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I can add the marker on the openlayer map using `Openlayers.Layer.markers` . 
But i cannot do this using  `OpenLayers.Feature.Vector` ? . Any one may help me..please...thanks in advance

Regards,
Boomiraj.P

Comment: can you post an example of what you've already tried?

Answer (score 8):

here's a simple example that should work.

```
var point = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
    new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(-111.04, 45.68));

var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("My Layer", {
    style: OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["default"]
});

map.addLayer(layer);
layer.addFeatures([point]);
```

Comment: Np. I suggest you start selecting correct answers for your questions because if you don't, people won't want to help you anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This also does the trick:

```
var point = new OpenLayers.LonLat( -0.1279688 ,51.5077286 ).transform(
    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    map.getProjectionObject());

var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
map.addLayer(markers);

markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(point));
```